# Android Wear action bar icons

Tags: android, icons, android-icons

Can I somewhere download the icons for wear action buttons (like this place sign on 'Check in here' page)? I checked the [design page](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html), but it seems to have only the guidelines docs. I tried using standard Android icons but they appear blurry abd unclear.

[image]